# scrollable views in drupal 6 is needed

Tags: drupal-6, scroll, drupal-views

I want to create a views with scrollable content. I've searched using google and found this : http://drupal.org/project/scrollable  but it is abandoned.

Is there anything similar to it ? I use Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

there are other modules available like ,

```
http://drupal.org/project/scrollable_content
http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll
http://drupal.org/project/infinitescroll
```